# systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store

Tags: redis

A little rodeo with redis. The error issued by redis is pretty unspecific ...

When doing `journalctl -xe` I got:

```
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 05 20:53:34 servername systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit redis-server.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 05 20:53:34 servername systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
-- Subject: A start job for unit redis-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit redis-server.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 184424 and the job result is failed.
```

When doing `sudo service redis status`:

```
sudo service redis status
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset:     enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-11-05 20:53:35 UTC; 11min ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
         man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 1468552 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 05 20:53:35 servername systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Nov 05 20:53:35 servername systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
Nov 05 20:53:35 servername systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 05 20:53:35 servername systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 05 20:53:35 servername systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

So how to resolve?

Comment: Check the logs.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Actually I did but I was not able to interprete the error message `systemd supervision requested, but NOTIFY_SOCKET not found` correctly. My answer below however allows random redis users to track the cause of the error faster I guess.

Comment: Huh? I don't see that error anywhere in your question. That made it impossible to answer. You should make sure to include all relevant information when posting.

Comment: You were too fast. :) I was at the same time typing my solution. Anyhow, indeed I should have added this. My answer is for the dummies like me, i.e. hopefully helps them track the cause better in a way or at least have an additional path to go about it. This is the only reason why I posted the question.

Answer (score 3):

So I started searching for solutions covering the "systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store" and "redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly." issue.

None of the offered solutions seemed to help or make sense. However finding the true cause of the issue was quite easy by issuing `/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf`. This checked the configuration file and I got the following information:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 151
>>> 'supervised yes'
Invalid option for 'supervised'. Allowed values: 'upstart', 'systemd', 'auto', or 'no'
```

After changing `supervised yes` to `supervised systemd` everything was fluff. Voilà!

In the end it was a senior moments error to add the wrong configuration to the file. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with redis-sentinel on Ubuntu after some upgrades

I added line supervised systemd  to /etc/redis/sentinel.conf  and start works.